# Logger module in child processes from os.fork()

Tags: python, logging, child-process

I have had a hard time understanding all the documentation on the logger module and forking processes.

My goal is to have each child process that's worked to write to their own separate log file.

This seems to work but I just want to try and verify that this is the correct way.

```
import os
import logging


def generate_primes(number):
    logger = logging.getLogger(str(os.getpid()) + ':logger')

    for num in range(number + 1):
       # prime numbers are greater than 1
       if num > 1:
           for i in range(2,num):
               if (num % i) == 0:
                   break
           else:
               logger.info('child:' + str(os.getpid()) + ':' + str(num))

def start_workers():
    logger = logging.getLogger('parent:prime')
    logger.info('parent forking')

    for child in range(10):
        pid = os.fork()

        if not pid:

            logger = logging.getLogger('child:' + str(os.getpid()))
            fh = logging.FileHandler('logs/child_primes_' + str(os.getpid()) + '.log')
            logger.addHandler(fh)

            generate_primes(10000)

            os._exit(0)
        else:
            os.waitpid(pid, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/parent_primes.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger('parent:prime')

    logger.info('Fork parent/child logging example.')
    logger.info('Starting children')

    start_workers()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas, your solutions looks good. I have few remarks regarding the code style.

1. The following code looks a bit strange to me:

   ```
   for num in range(number + 1):
       # prime numbers are greater than 1
       if num > 1:
           for i in range(2,num):
           ...
   ```

   You can easily replace it with:

   ```
   for num in range(2, number + 1):
       for i in range(2, num):
       ...
   ```
2. Do not use string concatenations, they are making your code less readable. Better use the `.format()` method of the string:

   ```
   'child:' + str(os.getpid()) + ':' + str(num)

   # Better:
   'child:{pid}:{num}'.format(pid=os.getpid(), num=num)
   ```
3. In order to not put the meta information to every logging request, you can use logging formatters. Please check that doc for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules.
4. To simplify logging creation and make a code a bit more readable, you can create a function `get_logger`:

   ```
   def get_logger(pid):
       file_name = 'logs/child_primes_{}.log'.format(pid)
       file_handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
       name = 'child:{}'.format(pid)
       logger = logging.getLogger(name)
       logger.addHandler(file_handler)
       # TODO: Add a formater here
       return logger
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few things that can be improved:

- `for i in range(2,num)`: You should have whitespace after the comma: `range(2, num)`
- `fh`: this is a bad name for a file handler: `file_handler` would be a much better name
- In the following lines, you have extra lines, that should be removed:

> ```
> for child in range(10):
>     pid = os.fork()
>
>     if pid:
>
>         logger = logging.getLogger(str(os.getpid()) + ':logger')
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I updated those lines. I'm looking more to verify that this would work as expected.